# Stratification of the affine grassmannian for $G = GL_2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Apologies for a very stupid question.

I am trying to understand closure of strata in the complex affine grassmannian for $GL_2$. Recall that $Gr = GL_2(K)/GL_2(O)$, where $K = \mathbb C((t))$ and $O = \mathbb C[[t]]$.

We can identify $Gr$ with the set of lattices in $K^2$, the $GL_2(O)$-submodules $E \subset K^2$ such that there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $$t^N E_0 \subset E \subset t^{-N}E_0$$ where $E_0$ is the "standard" lattice $E_0 = Oe_1 \oplus Oe_2$ ($e_1, e_2$ is the canonical basis of $K^2$).

Let $b \leq a$ two relative integers. We define the following strata : $$S_{a,b} = \{E : t^a E_0 \subset E \subset t^b E_0 : (a,b) \text{ is the tighest possible bound}\}$$

Proposition 4.1 of these [notes](https://people.math.umass.edu/%7Ecelliott/Affine_Grassmannian.pdf) says :

$$ \overline{S_{a,b}} = \bigcup_{0 \leq i \leq \frac{|a-b|}{2}} S_{a-i,b+i}$$

Assume we know $\overline{S_{a,b}} \supset \bigcup_{0 \leq i \leq \frac{|a-b|}{2}} S_{a-i,b+i}$. To deduce the other inclusion, we just want to see that $\bigcup_{0 \leq i \leq \frac{|a-b|}{2}} S_{a-i,b+i}$ is closed. To do this, consider the determinant map $\det : Gr \to Gr(GL_1) = \mathbb Z $, which is given by $\det(S_{a,b}) = a+b.$ It is claimed that the preimage is exactly the set we wanted to show to be closed, and hence we are done.

**Question** : How to finish the proof ? I don't understand the claim. Indeed, $$\det( \bigcup_{0 \leq i \leq \frac{|a-b|}{2}} S_{a-i,b+i}) = a + b$$

but it seems to me that the preimage $\det^{-1}(a+b) = \bigcup_{i \leq \frac{a-b}{2}} S_{a-i,b+i} $ is bigger than the union of strata we considered, and I don't see how to conclude that $\bigcup_{0 \leq i \leq \frac{|a-b|}{2}} S_{a-i,b+i}$ is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple : we have $S_{a,b} \subset \overline S_{a+1,b-1}$. So $\bigcup_{i > 0} S_{a+i,b-i}$ is open inside $\bigcup_{i \leq \frac{a-b}{2}} S_{a-i,b+i}$, and $\bigcup_{0 \leq i \leq \frac{a-b}{2}} S_{a-i,b+i}$ is closed.